# Finding array elements close to another array in space?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, logical-operators

I basically want to use the function `ismember`, but for a range. For example, I want to know what data points in `array1` are within `n` distance to `array2`, for each element in `array2`.

I have the following:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
array2 = [2,2,3,10,20,40,50]
```

I want to know what values in `array2` are `<= 2` away from `array1`:

```
indices(1,:) (where array1(1) = 1)     = [1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
indices(2,:) (where array1(2) = 2)     = [1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
indices(3,:) (where array1(3) = 3)     = [1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
indices(4,:) (where array1(4) = 4)     = [1 1 1 0 0 0 0]
indices(5,:) (where array1(5) = 5)     = [0 0 1 0 0 0 0]
```

Drawbacks:

My `array1` is 496736 elements, my `array2` is 9268 elements, so aI would rather not use a loop.

Comment: I expect the output would be an array of size `[496736 x 9268]`.

Comment: that is correct

Comment: You got some nice answers here, but the right approach of course is to build a binary tree to convert the search from O(n^2) to O(n log n). In multiple dimensions you’d use an R-tree to find nearby points. In 1D it’s a lot more trivial even.

Comment: I rolled back your answer summarising edit. Please reserve the question-space for only the *question* itself. If you would like to comment on individual answers, please comment on them. If you want to make a comparison between answers (be it timing, memory or syntax wise) you can add your own answer to do so if you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/), introduced in MATLAB R2016b, you can simply write:

```matlab
abs(array1.' - array2) <= 2

ans =
  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
```

For earlier MATLAB versions, you can get this using the [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) function:

```matlab
abs(bsxfun(@minus, array1.', array2)) <= 2

ans =
  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
  1  1  1  0  0  0  0
  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
```

Hope that helps!

P.S. On the "MATLAB is slow for loops" myth, please have a look [at that blog post](http://www.matlabtips.com/matlab-is-no-longer-slow-at-for-loops/) for example.

---

**EDIT:** Please read [Adriaan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57952662/11089932) on the RAM consumption using this and/or his approach!

Comment: The `bsxfun` solution also borks on memory. Implicit expansion is quite the haul-over apparently!

Answer (score 6):

Looping is a valid option here. Intialise an array `output` to the size of `array1 X array2`, then loop over all elements in `array1` an subtract `array2` from that, then check whether the absolute value is less than or equal to `2`:

```
array1 = [1,2,3,4,5];
array2 = [2,2,3,10,20,40,50];

output = zeros(numel(array1), numel(array2),'logical');

for ii = 1:numel(array1)
   output(ii,:) = abs(array1(ii)-array2)<=2;
end
output =

     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
```

i.e. loops are not the problem.

Thanks to Rahnema1's suggestion, you can initialise `output` directly as a logical matrix:

```
output = zeros(numel(array1),numel(array2),'logical');
```

whose size is just 4.3GB.

---

On timings: Hans' code runs in a matter of seconds for `array1 = 5*rand(496736,1); array2 = 25*rand(9286,1);`, the looped solution takes about 15 times longer. Both solutions are equal to one another. obcahrdon's `ismembertol` solution is somewhere in between on my machine.

---

On RAM usage:

- Both implicit expansion, as per Hans' answer, as well as the loop suggested in mine work with just 4.3GB RAM on your expanded problem size (496736*9286)
- [`pdist2` as per Luis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57953509/5211833) and `bsxfun` as per Hans' on the other hand try to create an intermediate double matrix of 34GB (which doesn't even fit in my RAM, so I cannot compare timings).
- [obchardon's `ismembertol`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57955752/5211833) solution outputs a different form of the solution, and takes ~5.04GB (highly dependent on the amount of matches found, the more, the larger this number will be).

In general this leads me to the conclusion that implicit expansion should be your option of choice, but if you have R2016a or earlier, `ismembertol` or a loop is the way to go.

Comment: Good hint on the RAM consumption! You know Ander's usual comment on that: Buy more RAM. :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you have the Statistics Toolbox, you can use [`pdist2`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html) to compute the distance matrix:

```
result = pdist2(array1(:), array2(:)) <= 2;
```

As noted by [@Adriaan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5211833/adriaan), this is not efficient for large input sizes. In that case a better approach is a loop with preallocation of the logical matrix output, as in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57952662/2586922).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `ismembertol` with some specific option:

```
A       = [1,2,3,4,5];
B       = [2,2,3,10,20,40,5000];
tol     = 2;
[~,ind] = ismembertol([A-tol;A+tol].',[B-tol;B+tol].',tol, 'ByRows', true, ...
    'OutputAllIndices', true, 'DataScale', [1,Inf])
```

It will create a 5x1 cell array containing the corresponding *linear* indice

```
ind{1} = [1,2,3]
ind{2} = [1,2,3]
...
ind{5} = [3]
```

In this case using *linear* indices instead of *logical* indices will greatly reduce the memory consumption.

Comment: Thanks! I added to RAM comparison to my answer. As yours give a different form, its size is different. In this case it's 700MB *larger* than a pure logical matrix. I guess if you expect few matches, this solution would be more viable than the others. Is there a way to output the indices as integers, as that's what they are anyway? For the OP's full case `ind` will be a cell containing almost 500k double arrays.