# Is bsxfun still optimal in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, bsxfun

I did bump into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951453/in-matlab-when-is-it-optimal-to-use-bsxfun) question while searching for this topic, but this one seems to be outdated.

Reading https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b , implicit expansion was introduced in 2016b, but I can still find the reference codes in the papers using `bsxfun` for arithmetic expansion. So I assume that there are some circumstances that make `bsxfun` preferable to other methods.

I did compare the speeds between `bsxfun`, `repmat`, and implicit expansion (I used the code of Jonas from the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12951453/in-matlab-when-is-it-optimal-to-use-bsxfun))

The below shows the comparison in calculation time using `tic` `toc`:

[image: Comparison of calculation time using tic and toc]

which shows that implicit expansion is clearly faster than `bsxfun` or `repmat`. Is there any reason to use `bsxfun` nowadays?

Here is the code I used to compare the speed:

```
n = 300;
k=100; %# k=100 for the second graph
a = ones(10,1);
rr = zeros(n,1);
bb = zeros(n,1);
ntt = 100;
tt = zeros(ntt,1);
for i=1:n;
   r = rand(1,i*k);
   for it=1:ntt;
      tic,
      x = bsxfun(@plus,a,r);
      tt(it) = toc;
   end;
   bb(i) = median(tt);
   for it=1:ntt;
      tic,
      y = repmat(a,1,i*k) + repmat(r,10,1);
      tt(it) = toc;
   end;
   rr(i) = median(tt);
   for it=1:ntt;
      tic,
      z = a + r;
      tt(it) = toc;
   end;
   gg(i) = median(tt);
end
figure;
plot(bb,'b')
hold on
plot(rr,'r')
plot(gg,'g')
legend(["bsxfun","repmat","implicit"])
```

Comment: Note also that implicit expansion seems to do some (unexpected) [optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57954599/does-matlabs-implicit-broadcasting-optimise-based-on-surrounding-code) that `bsxfun` does not do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All `bsxfun` does is **B**inary **S**ingleton e**X**pansion. It's more typing than the, now usual, implicit expansion. I'd guess The MathWorks kept `bsxfun` around for backwards compatibility, but no longer works on it; it might even internally just map to implicit expansion.

[The documentation on `bsxfun`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) states:

> It is recommended that you replace most uses of `bsxfun` with direct calls to the functions and operators that support implicit expansion. Compared to using `bsxfun`, implicit expansion offers faster speed of execution, better memory usage, and improved readability of code. For more information, see [Compatible Array Sizes for Basic Operations](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/compatible-array-sizes-for-basic-operations.html).

Additionally, implicit expansion seems to have internal optimisations beyond what `bsxfun` does, see [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57954599/does-matlabs-implicit-broadcasting-optimise-based-on-surrounding-code).
More helpful links can be found in [this answer by nirvana-msu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39925305/5211833), amongst others to blogs by MathWorks employees discussing this.

So I'd say that the only reason to use `bsxfun` instead of implicit expansion would be if you'd run the code on a pre-2016b version of MATLAB.

Comment: What a great tradition reading the documentation is :D

Comment: It *might* also be useful if the binary operation applied does not do implicit  singleton expansion. Maybe it’s a MEX-file function you wrote yourself. But yes, backwards compatibility is a very important reason to keep it around.

Comment: @CrisLuengo that's probably implied in the docs through *most uses*, rather than *all uses*.